# Azure VM size A1 Basic not available

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-v5.0

I'm following an official Microsoft tutorial on Azure with free trial where they ask us to create a `VM` of size `A1 Basic` on a region closer to you. But when I select any of the following regions, I see no `A1 Basic` size as shown in the image below: `East US, East US 2, Central US, North Central US`

[image]

Comment: Obvious question, but have you click the "view all" button at the top?

Comment: @SamCogan I don't recall seeing "View All" link (that I've used before). So, I assume it was showing all the available offerings. However, after reading your inquiry, I went back to the VM `A2 Basic` (that I had created instead) and clicked on `Size` link under `Settings` and noticed that `A1 Basic` was available for resizing. Could that mean maybe I ignored the `View All` link at the first place; otherwise, I would have seen the `A1 Basic` size option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1 Basic VM only has one CPU. According to your screenshot, it seems that your filter conditions is vCPU larger than 1.

When you select VM size. Please check following screenshot.

[image]

Then you could select A1 Basic size VM.

Comment: Hi, could you find A1 basic size on Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes I did (thank you). I forgot to mark your response.